UPS Quantum View API using OAuth2.0 JSON data discrepancies
For UPS QuantumView API, in the YAML documentation, they have mentioned some properties we will get in an array format for the v2 version. For the v1 version, we will get those properties in an array if there is more than one object and a single object if there is only 1.
But for the v2 version also, I am getting some properties in object format instead of an array. e.g. SubscriptionFile, Package, Activity, ShipmentReferenceNumber. Is there any issue with the v2 version of QuantumView API?
or API YAML documentation,https://github.com/UPS-API/api-documentation/blob/main/QuantumView.yaml#L470 might lag behind actual implementations due to updates or changes.
